# Problem with internal USB hub & my smartphone

Tags: usb, hardware

I have a problem when plugging in a smartphone, as `journalctl` shows below:

```
jul 19 17:28:43 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
jul 19 17:28:43 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
jul 19 17:28:43 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
jul 19 17:28:44 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
jul 19 17:28:44 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
jul 19 17:28:44 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71                                
jul 19 17:28:44 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd                   
jul 19 17:28:44 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.                             
jul 19 17:28:44 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.                             
jul 19 17:28:45 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71                           
jul 19 17:28:45 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd                   
jul 19 17:28:45 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
jul 19 17:28:45 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
jul 19 17:28:45 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
jul 19 17:28:45 newhope.belkin.home kernel: usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

`lsusb` output is as follows:

```
[sergio@newhope ~]$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1bcf:289a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also, you can take a look to the usb-devices output at http://pastebin.com/NHD5WBSu.

**NOTE:** I'm using Fedora 22: kernel 4.0.8-300.fc22.x86_64

#### Questions

- Why does it happen?
- Is it a (kernel|udev) bug?
- Is a power issue of internal hub?

Comment: Can you add the specifics of what device this is? Also what motherboard/computer are you using?

Comment: Here you are: Machine:   System: Dell product: Inspiron 5423 serial: 2L87MW1, Mobo: Dell model: 0F45CW v: A13 serial: .2L87MW1.CN7620638N008Z. Bios: Dell v: A13 date: 05/18/2013

Comment: What's the smart phone?

Comment: Samsug Galaxy Grand Prime SM-G530M, Android 4.4.4

Comment: When you plug it in what does `dmesg` show?

Comment: Are you merely trying to get files on/off the device? I've basically stopped trying to do that and simply access the devices over my LAN using AirDroid or wifi file transfer instead, just an alternative if you're completely stuck. I'm not seeing much when I google for this device + Linux so I'm thinking your just out of luck w/ it plus your HW/Linux combo.

Comment: dmesg output is as journactl output. AirDroid it's nice although I prefer someone more privacy-friendly.

Comment: Then look at [wifi file transfer app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransfer&hl=en) instead. I used that to get files on/off my Nexus 7. It was problematic w/ some of my Linux desktops/laptops and I went that way instead.

Comment: Interesting, I've tried FTP Server of Pieter Pareit, sadly I could not get a preview of the images

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem many times with a variety of USB devices. My general approach to start debugging these issues has been the following:

- Plug the device directly into the computer vs. into a USB hub that's connected into the computer. For whatever reason the daisy chaining of devices through a hub like this can cause problems (this isn't a Linux unique problem, happens to me on Windows and OSX too).
- Confirm that the device works on another computer (preferably Linux)
- Google the device + name to see if other's have gotten it to work on any version of Linux (take note of which versions people have gotten it to work, if any)

You have to pay special attention to 3 things when dealing with USB devices.
- What brand/motherboard is hosting the USB ports you're attempting to connect to
- What the actual USB device is you're attempting to connect
- What distro (Linux Kernel) you're running on the above mentioned motherboard/hardware

It's been my experience that USB devices may work perfectly fine on one combination but give you fits on something completely different.